# How to send an email to multiple recepient with contact form?

Tags: emails

I want to send an email to multiple recepients when the contact form is submitted. By default when contact form is submitted it is sending mail to default email id which is saved in system configuration.

How can we add multiple email addresses which will receive messages when any user submitted the contact form?

Comment: Puh, it's really difficult to guide you here as there simply is too little information for this broad question. I mean what have you tried so far? Do you know `hook_mail`? Have you tried anything yourself to solve your problem? Please update your question to give us a hint where exactly you got stuck.

Comment: Simply googling your problem gives me so many hits you can check out. https://www.google.com/search?q=drupal+contact+form+recipients

Comment: I want to know only way how can we achieve that. I have searched in google but nothing was helpful

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible implementation to achieve what you're asking about:

- define a new eMail ID, say `x@sample.com`.
- configure this `x@sample.com` to automatically forward all incoming eMail to your "multiple eMail addresses".
- in your form, use `x@sample.com`as the email ID where these forms should be eMailed to (which will then be forwarded after you completed the prior step).

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple email in contact form setting itself separated by comma.
I am attaching the screenshot for reference.

[image]